# Rectangular discoloration on laptop screen

Tags: ubuntu, laptop, graphics-card, display, kubuntu

Recently, I've developed a strange problem on my laptop (Samsung ATIV Book 8). The left portion of the screen has a discoloration that seems to be changing over time and behaves differently depending on the color it's over. Taking a screenshot doesn't show the discoloration.

Yesterday, colors close to a perfect gray (RGB values equal) were discolored on a rectangle on the left side, becoming more blue as it approached white, and becoming more red as it approached black. Here is an example of the discoloration with the original on the right and the discoloration on the left.

[image]

Today, the discoloration changed, and seems to turn things green / grey, and it also flickers now.

[image]
[image]

I'm running Kubuntu 16.04, if that's any help, and the graphics card in the computer is a Radeon 8870M. If anyone knows what could be causing this problem and how I could fix it, I would be very grateful.

Comment: LCD screens don't get burn-in, and it's a large rectangular area.  So it likely isn't the screen, itself.  But it's probably related to the display hardware rather than a problem with the graphics card or drivers.  Start by ruling out the display card and driver by connecting an external monitor.  One other idea to rule out: it's possible that the discolored area is a defined zone of the touchscreen that is being improperly "highlighted", possibly due to OS or software corruption.  Boot a live session on a DVD or USB drive to see if the problem exists there.  (cont'd)

Comment: If it's in the display and it's still under warranty, have it repaired.  If it's out of warranty, open the lid shell and check the ribbon cables that connect the display panel to the electronics inside the lid.  Look for a loose connection or corrosion.  Check for a bad solder joint or break that makes intermittent contact.  The color cast may be a block of subpixels of one color adding to or subtracting from what is being displayed.  The flickering may be a marginal connection or failing component, perhaps affected by temperature.  (cont'd)

Comment: If you don't see an obvious problem, try using a can of compressed air to cool the electronics inside the lid to see if the problem changes.  If it is a fault in the display but isn't an obvious problem, it is likely to be more expensive to diagnose and repair than to replace the display.  And since it's a touchscreen, replacement will be expensive enough that you might weigh the value vs. getting a new machine.

Comment: Thank you! I will try your suggestions as soon as possible